# Recorrer un array y verificar con true si todos los elementos son iguales o false si se encuentra un elemento distinto, con Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, function

La consigna es:

> deberás crear una Función que tome un Arreglo como Parámetro y devuelva `true` si todos los elementos del Arreglo son idénticos. De lo contrario, deberá devolver `false`. Salvo que sea necesario, tu Función no debe recorrer todo el Arreglo si no es idéntico. Es decir, al momento que encuentre una diferencia deberá cortar.

Esto fue lo que hice yo:

```
let arregloNuevo = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

let arregloFalso = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5]

let isUniform = array => {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        const element = array[index];
        count = 1

        if (array[count] == element) {
            return true
        } else {

            return false
        }
        count++
    }
}
```

Primero declaré los arreglos de prueba `arregoNuevo` y `arregloFalso`, después ejecuté la función con *arrow functions* y usé `for` para iterar el arreglo, el corte es cuando el index de `for` llegue a cumplir el índice del arreglo `.length`.

Comment: detalla mas el codigo, no tiene sentido el codigo que tienes de ejemplo

Comment: Siendo una tarea, antes de usar un método de la clase Array, como indican en las respuestas (correctas, no digo que no) pregúntate si es lo que el profesor espera.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer la validación usando **every**.

> El método `every()` prueba si todos los elementos de la matriz pasan la
> prueba implementada por la función proporcionada. Devuelve un valor
> booleano.

```js
let arregloNuevo = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
let arregloFalso = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5]

const todoIgual = arr => arr.every(v => v === arr[0]);

console.log(todoIgual(arregloNuevo)); // true

console.log(todoIgual(arregloFalso)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es usando `.every` pero también se puede usar `.some` (`!arr.some(e => e !== arr[0])`) o un loop, lo que hay que asegurar es no recorrer todo el array, en la primera condición que no se de, debe dejar de iterar. En el caso de funciones y for, es clave usar el `continue` y el `return`. Te dejo un ejemplo de como modificaría tu abordaje:

```js
let arregloNuevo = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

let arregloFalso = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5]

let isUniform = array => {

  const comparacion = array[0]; // <-- El elemento lo dejamos fuera del loop

  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {

    if (array[index] === comparacion) { // <-- Siempre comparamos con el primero

      continue; // <-- Si está todo bien seguimos con el siguiente item 
  
    } else {

      return false; // <-- Se termina la función y la iteración en false

    }


  }

  return true; // <-- Si recorrió todos es que está todo bien, !!fuera del for

}

console.log(isUniform(arregloNuevo))
console.log(isUniform(arregloFalso))
```